# Which expiry date(s) require a Ad Hoc Distribution redeployment?

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution

When preparing an app for Ad Hoc Distribution, there are three things within the Apple developer account have expiry dates:

- **Active developer account.** The expiry date for this shows up on the Membership page as *Expiration date* and also as *Device reset date*.
- **iOS distribution certificate.** The expiry date for this shows up on the *Certificates > Production* page.
- **iOS provisioning profile.** The expiry date for this shows up on the *Provisioning Profiles > Distribution* page when you click on the profile.

After I've deployed the app onto a device, which of the above expiry dates will cause the app to stop working if I don't redeploy? e.g. If my developer account expires first, will the app keep working if I don't redeploy?

Comment: The iOS (AdHoc) provisioning profiles date, which also takes  the Distribution Certificates date into account.

Comment: Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the provisioning profile using the certificate. The provisioning profile uses the certificate expiry date as its expiry date.

You then install the app to devices using the provisioning profile and it is the expiry date of the profile that determines the expiry date of app.

Comment: What happens when you installed the app with an ad-hoc profile that is about to expire and updated the remote profile with a new certificate, so that the same (now remote) profile gets a new expiry of a year? Does the app "know" that the expiry of its profile was extended forward, or will the app expire according to the date of the local profile?